# Utm метка в заявке

Tags: php

Нужно чтобы в заявке с формы отображалось ключевое слово, по которому пользователь перешел на сайт. Кто-нибудь знает как реализовать? Обработчик формы ниже:

```
$headers= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "From: <admin@admin.com>\r\n";

$name  = trim($_POST["name"]);
$phone  = trim($_POST["phone"]);
$message = "<b>Ваше имя:</b> $name <br><b>Ваш телефон:</b> $phone";

$subject = "Заявка";
mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers);
header('Location: /success/');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При переходе на сайт сохраняйте метки. Например, в сессию.

```
session_start();
....
$_SESSION['utm_source'] = $_GET['utm_source'] // и т.д.
```

Далее, при формировании email формы, прячьте в неё метки из сессии.

```
<input type="hidden" name="utm[sourse]" value="<?= $_GET['utm_source'] ?>" /> // и и.д.
```

Ну и ловите их в обработчике и подставляете куда надо. Можете их и вовсе доставать из сессии уже в обработчике и не тянуть постом.

Comment: Никогда не задавался таким вопросом, но: $_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER] подскажет вам, от куда к вам пришли. Дальше при помощи регулярки можете достать домен. Ну или добавьте ещё одну кастомную метку, если вы точно знаете где запускаете компанию и хардово указывайте в ней источник. Но вроде для этой цели как раз и служит метка utm_source.